# Removing Embedded Header in Dynamically Generated Destinations

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I wanted to disable the embedded header in a message, when using dynamically generated destination, similar to example from [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#dynamicdestination) (say output topics = dyntopic1,dyntopic2,...).

I've set properties like the below, but I'm still getting the header, any suggestions if I've missed something?

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.group=test-ogroup
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.binder=kafka
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.headerMode=raw
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.content-type=text/plain
```

Kafka = v0.10

spring-cloud-dependencies.version = Edgware.M1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting producer properties for dynamic destinations is not available with Spring Cloud Stream 1.3 or lower.

If you know the properties ahead of time, you can set them in properties...

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.dyntopic1.producer.headerMode=raw
```

The feature has been [added to master](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/commit/83fa5f3858621ae0382dbef7358366a588804222) and will be available in the 2.0 release.

**EDIT**

It can be done with Edgware as long as you don't mind using reflection to reset the flag. You have to replace the channel resolver bean.

I tested this with Edgware.SR1 - you really shouldn't be using M1 any more, that was a pre-release milestone.

I can't guarantee that this will work with newer versions because it is messing with framework internals.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class So48543143Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So48543143Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(MessageChannel routeChannel) {
        return args -> {
            routeChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("foo"));
        };
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "routeChannel")
    @Bean
    public AbstractMappingMessageRouter router(MyBinderAwareChannelResolver resolver) {
        ExpressionEvaluatingRouter router = new ExpressionEvaluatingRouter(new LiteralExpression("foo"));
        router.setDefaultOutputChannelName("default");
        router.setChannelResolver(resolver);
        return router;
    }

    @Bean
    public MyBinderAwareChannelResolver binderAwareChannelResolver(BindingService bindingService,
            AbstractBindingTargetFactory<? extends MessageChannel> bindingTargetFactory,
            DynamicDestinationsBindable dynamicDestinationsBindable) {
        return new MyBinderAwareChannelResolver(bindingService, bindingTargetFactory, dynamicDestinationsBindable);
    }

    public static class MyBinderAwareChannelResolver extends BinderAwareChannelResolver {

        public MyBinderAwareChannelResolver(BindingService bindingService,
                AbstractBindingTargetFactory<? extends MessageChannel> bindingTargetFactory,
                DynamicDestinationsBindable dynamicDestinationsBindable) {
            super(bindingService, bindingTargetFactory, dynamicDestinationsBindable);
        }

        @Override
        public MessageChannel resolveDestination(String channelName) {
            MessageChannel channel = super.resolveDestination(channelName);
            DirectFieldAccessor dfa = new DirectFieldAccessor(channel);
            AbstractDispatcher dispatcher = (AbstractDispatcher) dfa.getPropertyValue("dispatcher");
            dfa = new DirectFieldAccessor(dispatcher);
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Set<MessageHandler> handlers = (Set<MessageHandler>) dfa.getPropertyValue("handlers");
            // there should be exactly one handler
            MessageHandler handler = handlers.iterator().next();
            dfa = new DirectFieldAccessor(handler);
            dfa.setPropertyValue("embedHeaders", false);
            return channel;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Will the 2.0 release work with Kafka v0.10? Also, is there anyway I can remove it through code itself? As it would be unwieldy to keep adding more configuration properties for every topic I have.

Comment: No 2.0 won't work with 0.10 (which is very old, I would recommend you move to a newer version of Kafka ASAP. I edited my answer with a work-around which works, as long as you don't mind using reflection.

Comment: Thanks for the help, will use this as I don't foresee any Kafka upgrades on my env anytime soon. Cheers!